# Problems with validation using ajax Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have been trying to solve the validation problem with ajax, for that I have created a partial that when the event happens, call the partial of the errors, although, does the render, I don't know how to return it to the form view within a modal, here my code:

**_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for @enterprise, remote: true, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

      <div id="error-messages"></div>    

      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <%= f.label :nombre %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Nombre" %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <%= f.label :correo_electronico %>
          <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Correo electronico" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <%= f.label :contraseña %>
          <%= f.text_field :password, placeholder: "Contraseña" %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <%= f.label :confirmar_contraseña %>
          <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirmar contraseña" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <%= f.submit "Guardar", class: "button" %>
        </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @enterprise.errors.empty? %>
  $('#exampleModal1').foundation('close');
<% else %>
  $('#error_messages').html('<%= render partial: "enterprises/shared/errors" %>');
<% end %>
```

**enterprise/shared/_errors.html.erb**

```
<% if @enterprise.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(@enterprise.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this article from being saved:
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @enterprise.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**enterprises_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @enterprise = Enterprise.new(enterprise_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @enterprise.save
        format.html { redirect_to @enterprise, notice: 'enterprise was successfully created.' }
        format.js   {}
        format.json { render json: @enterprise, status: :created, location: @enterprise }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @enterprise.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Does your _form.html.erb has div with id as 'error_messages' ?

Comment: I change the code, and put the div errors-messages in the form, but I don't get it, need to specify the render in the update in format.js?

Answer (score 0):

copy code of create.js.erb to new.js.erb and try again

Comment: Nothing Gautam, and this happens whit update, new.js and edit.js only do the render to the form